# Best solution for simple game graphics in C#/.net

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm making a turn-based top-down game in C#. The graphics requirements are pretty simple: it's entirely 2D, requires drawing some images taken from graphics files (perhaps rotating them first), line drawing to make a hex grid and the ability to place text at any position on the screen.

I'm wondering what the best API is for doing these graphics. Is XNA overkill for this, is there something more appropriate? Thanks (I have zero experience of graphics or game development in .net so don't be afraid to dumb-down any answers).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend XNA for this.  If you don't want some of the overhead of XNA, I've found SlimDX to be a very nice little framework.  They also provide some basic game classes to make this type of thing easy.

Doing your drawing directly in WPF is also fairly easy, but more difficult to extend later.  XNA and SlimDX give you access to shaders, very fine grained control of alpha blending, as well as the potential to easily extend portions into 3D later if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Farseer Physics engine before which was pretty cool and extremely easy to pickup (I am an enterprise developer, not a game developer).  It works for Silverlight so you could actually make your game web based.  I would suggest silverlight or WPF for 2D.

http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics

Comment: I use that for a game.  It might be overkill, but it should work.

Comment: Isn't Farseer a physics engine and not a rendering framework? How would this help him with the visual component in any way?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend WPF. Loading your graphics and moving them around should be fairly easy. Since WPF also is vector based, your line drawing is straight forward.

XNA would be the next step. Great support for sprite graphics and also gives you access to shaders.

Answer (score 1):

If it is as simple as it sounds, and not even real-time, maybe you don't need any of this stuff. Drawing a hex grid and some images should not be hard even without a game engine. Maybe WPF would be good for this.

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement you could just use plain C# and the GDI (for 2d rastering). However learning XNA is easy enough, and it'll serve you well once you decide to make a realtime game (2d or 3d) down the road. Either way have fun, and if XNA seems to complicated when your starting out, just drop back to GDI. Making games should be as fun as playing them :)

Answer (score 0):

XNA sounds like a good choise (it will better than using DirectX SDK !! and it is quite easy to learn)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using classes inside the `System.Drawing` namespace. And `XNA` is certainly  overkill for this type of stuff. Also you would introduse many dependencies for your small game which might be an unwanted thing for your gamers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/) - it's based on C# and it can be used for 2D. It might be overkill (including price), but for game development it's in general HUGE help.